# Implementing a custom sSortType and sort function for jQuery dataTables

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm having a hard time following the instructions on the [documentation](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) page. I have a table displaying the average time durations in one column, in the HH:MM format, e.g 10:45 means ten hours and forty-five minutes. I would like to be able to sort my entire table by the values in this column.

Here is my initialization code :

```
    var aoTable = $("#TableStatistic").dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid dt-header'<'span6'f><'span6'T>>t<'row-fluid dt-footer'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": ["xls", "pdf", "print"],
        "sSwfPath": "../Content/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    },
    "aaData": statisticsModel.byCategoriesList(),
    "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
    "bPaginate": false,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "CategoryName", "sTitle": "Reports.CategoryName" },
        { "mDataProp": "AverageTime", "sTitle": "Reports.AverageTime", "sSortDataType": "duration-desc"},
        { "mDataProp": "NumberOfProblemsSolved", "sTitle": "Reports.NumberOfProblemsSolved" }
    ],
    "oLanguage": MeridianTranslation.DataTable

});
```

Here is what **I ASSUME** to be the proper way to add a new sort function and a new sSortType into my table:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['duration-desc'] = function (x, y) {
    var xHours = parseInt(x.slice(0, x.indexOf(':')));
    var xMinutes = parseInt(x.slice(x.indexOf(':') + 1, x.length)) + xHours * 60;
    var yHours = parseInt(y.slice(0, y.indexOf(':')));
    var yMinutes = parseInt(y.slice(y.indexOf(':') + 1, y.length)) + yHours * 60;
    return ((xMinutes < yMinutes) ? -1 : ((xMinutes > yMinutes) ? 1 : 0));
});

jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['duration-asc'] = function (x, y) {
    var xHours = parseInt(x.slice(0, x.indexOf(':')));
    var xMinutes = parseInt(x.slice(x.indexOf(':')+1, x.length)) + xHours * 60;
    var yHours = parseInt(y.slice(0, y.indexOf(':')));
    var yMinutes = parseInt(y.slice(y.indexOf(':')+1, y.length)) + yHours * 60;
    return ((xMinutes < yMinutes) ? 1 : ((xMinutes > yMinutes) ? -1 : 0));
});
```

I suppose there is a much better way for extracting the number of minutes than the way I do it, but let's suppose my algorithm is valid. What must I do to initialize my dataTable properly and integrate this sort function and data type into it? The table itself renders properly, but when I try to sort the column in question, it sort itself lexicographically, as if it were a string.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should provide both a `<type>-asc` method and a `<type>-desc` method.

The sort is then based on the `sType` property of the column:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["duration-desc"] = function (x, y) {
    ...
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["duration-asc"] = function (x, y) {
    ...
}

var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
    "aaData": [
        [1, "Dinner", "0:40"],
        [2, "Study", "11:25"],
        [3, "Sleep", "7:30"]
    ],
    "aoColumns": [{
        ...
    }, {
        ...
    }, {
        ...
        "bSortable": true,
        "sType": "duration"
    }]

});
```

Here is a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/N3ckS/) example.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue before seeing your answer, but it's good to have it for future reference, nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: They are 2 elements from the corresponding key your data set that need to be compared. In the OP's case, those are 2 "duration" strings from the `AverageTime` column. It should return a value that follows the standard of `compareFunction` from [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), as this is a comparison-based sort.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what MasterAM said in a previous answer, here is how I completely solved my issue:

- **First**, when dealing with a custom data type, one needs a type detection method, like the one found on the dedicated doc [page](http://datatables.net/development/type-detection). The method must be placed BEFORE the dataTable init method. Here's what my method looks like, keeping in mind the HH:MM format I need to analyse:

  ```
  jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.push(function (sData) {
      var sValidChars = "0123456789:";
      var Char;
      for (i = 1 ; i < sData.length ; i++) {
          Char = sData.charAt(i);
          if (sValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) {
              return null;
          }
      }   
      if (sData.charAt(1) == ':' || sData.charAt(2) == ':') {
          return 'duration';
      }
      return null;
  });
  ```

  I named my data type `duration` accordingly.
- **Second**, you need to implement the ascending and descending sort functions such as the one I typed in the question (now edited correctly), which should ALSO be placed before the init method.
- **Finally**, you must tell the dataTable init method to expect the datatype inside the column you wish. This is done in the `aoColumns` array. In my case, this would mean:

  ```
  { "mDataProp": "AverageTime", "sTitle": "Reports.AverageTime", 'sType': 'duration' }
  ```

  The `asc` and `desc` will be appended once the user clicks on the header of the column, and that is why the I only wrote `duration` in the last line.

Comment: It would probably be a lot quicker and easier to use a regular expression to detect the desired pattern, in your case. You could also have the server send a numeric value (the number of minutes) and parse it into the display string by using an `mRender`.