# Datatable.js is not ordering dates in correct order

Tags: javascript, date, datatables

My js code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#self').DataTable({
    order: [1, "asc"],
    pageLength: 10,
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column'
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Where it says `order: [1, "asc"]`, this should be ordering my second column in number order. The column contains a date and time. Currently it orders it in number order rather than date order. For example it would order dates like this:

> 21/**02**/2107, 22/**01**/2017, 23/**02**/2017

Does anyone know if I can add something to this code to make it order by date instead of in number order?

Comment: This is because its sorting based on String value and not Date Value. You should look into writing your own custom sort function

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759814/implementing-a-custom-ssorttype-and-sort-function-for-jquery-datatables

Comment: Thanks Rajesh; I'll give this a go!