# Datatables jquery sorting OR search

Tags: jquery, datatables

I created an OR search which looks for word1 OR word2 rather than word1 AND word2. 
The way I did this is I created an input box for the search and added the following code (input id="myInput"):

```
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function ()  
 {
 regExSearch = this.value;
 regExSearch = regExSearch.replace(/\s+/g,"|");
 dataTable.search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();
 }  );
```

Now I want the search filter to sort the data as follows:
1st show all records with both word1 AND word2
2nd show all records with either word1 OR word2

Is that possible? If so where should this be added and how would I go about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20761806/4108884 -> maybe this can help you, it works like the custom array sorting functions - you have two values for comparision and you return -1, 1, or 0 depending on the comparision result

Comment: But it could be 2 or more values. What I was thinking was maybe to add a checkbox beside the search textbox. If checked find word1 AND word2, if unchecked find word1 OR word2. It works but I am having an issue refreshing the table when checkbox change status...

Comment: The function is comparing two values at a time but is applied over the whole collection, it is how most sorting algorithms work. For table refresh, you can call dataTable.ajax.reload(); Even if you are not using using ajax to populate data, it still should force a refresh.

Comment: The checkbox idea is not working but I like your idea. So I had this idea have my search do 2 searches: regExSearch = this.value;
 regExSearch = regExSearch.replace(/\s+/g,"|");
 dataTable.search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();   and also  regExSearch = this.value;
 dataTable.search(regExSearch, true, true).draw();  one search will do an OR and one will do an AND, then I sort but I looked at your link and I am having trouble following the algorithm...will have to look at it again. How do I store both searches and then tell my code to sort search1 and then search2...

Comment: "*1st show all records with both word1 AND word2 2nd show all records with either word1 OR word2*" I do not quite understand. Will "2th" not just be a subset of "1st". Rows where one of the words is present will just be repeating some of the rows where both words is present.

Comment: Yeah you are right there will be repetition...So I am back to using a checkbox to go from AND or OR search. The only problem I have when I click on the checkbox it only refreshes the table if I re-type something in the
 search box. I want the table to refresh once the checkbox changed status. Can't figure this out...

Comment: I found this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382569/jquery-datatables-or-search-filter
How can I add a checkbox that once checked select the OR function and once unchecked selects the AND function? I want it to autorefresh the table onchange of the checkbox