# Jquery Sortable table, will only sort one date column

Tags: jquery, datatables

We have a table of 4 columns 
2 columns are dates however only one will sort correctly (dd/mm/yyyy). The other just seems to sort by number

01/05/2019

01/06/2019

03/05/2019

04/06/2019

06/05/2019

06/06/2019

08/05/2019

09/05/2019

for full code please see Jsbin https://output.jsbin.com/wukixox/ or https://codepen.io/Chazlie/pen/GbWZWa

```
<div class="tracking-table" id="tracking-table-style">
 <div id="test-table-2">

<table id ="table-tracking" class="container sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>


 <th class="complete"> complete</th>
 <th class="process"> process</th>
 <th class="scanned"> scanned</th>
 <th class="goneaway"> despatch date</th>

   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>   
        <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">31/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">06/06/2019</td>
  </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">02/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">09/05/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">02/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">09/06/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">02/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">08/05/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">02/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">09/05/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">False</td>
<td class="process">Pattern Matching</td>
<td class="scanned">17/06/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">27/06/2019</td>
  </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">25/04/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">06/05/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">13/06/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">04/06/2019</td>

 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">13/06/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">03/05/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">29/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">01/05/2019</td>
  </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">29/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">01/06/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">False</td>
<td class="process">TOP OF FABRIC QUERY</td>
<td class="scanned">11/06/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">TBA</td>
  </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">16/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">16/05/2019</td>
  </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">16/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">17/06/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">16/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">18/05/2019</td>
 </tr> 
    <tr>

<td class="complete">True</td>
<td class="process">DD CARRIER</td>
<td class="scanned">16/05/2019</td>
<td class="goneaway">19/06/2019</td>
  </tr> 

</tbody>
</table> </div></div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );

    $('#table-tracking').DataTable( {
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 25,
    });
} );
```

This uses the datatables Jquery plugin

So the Scanned column works fine, Dispatched doesn't

editable JSbin https://jsbin.com/wukixox/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Because the Dispatched column dosen't contain only dates `<td class="goneaway">TBA</td>`

Comment: Tested and you are correct. Is it possible to do anything about this? This is an API data that comes in via an XML which we then out put as a table for users to see. So Columns will have TBA. Is there anything we can do so if TBA is in column that it ignores it? or anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is a non date formatted string data in your despatch date's column, so datatable won't parse it as a date column.

**SOLUTION 1:**
You can separate your displayed data and the data which used by the sorting algorithm. You need to add a data attribute all of your td's from the 4th columns which should contains only date strings. In your case you should write eg.: 00/00/0000 on the td's which have not date formatted strings. More info: https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data

```
...
<tr>
    ...
    <td data-order="00/00/0000" class="goneaway">TBA</td> //Check the data-order attribute's value
</tr>
<tr>
    ...
    <td data-order="06/06/2019" class="goneaway">06/06/2019</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
```

**Better solution** if you write your own sorting algorithm. Example:
[Implementing a custom sSortType and sort function for jQuery dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759814/implementing-a-custom-ssorttype-and-sort-function-for-jquery-datatables)